# Convert Linq results to JSON array

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a datatable which I am attempting to send to a webpage in the JSON format

`{"Heading":[{"value":"someTitle", "id":0, children:[]},...]}`

I have attempted to cobble together code in order to do this.  The datatable rows contain 3 columns: id, heading and value.

Here is what I have:

```
JObject ret = JObject.Parse("{ isAdmin: false, data: {} }");

...

var headings = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select row["Heading"].ToString()).Distinct();

//var jsonResults = JObject.Parse(results);
foreach (var heading in headings.ToArray())
{
    var dArray =
        (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
         where row["Heading"].ToString() == heading
         select new { id = row["id"], value = row["reportTitle"] }
        ).ToArray();
    var jArr = new JArray(dArray);
    ret["data"][heading] = jArr;
}
```

The exception I am receiving is

> Could not determine JSON object type for type >f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Object,System.Object].

How can I restructure this code to receive the results I need?

Comment: Where do you receive that exception? At the first line above?

Comment: You need to provide the table structure and query/code that is yielding the `dt` DataTable. Otherwise it's hard to know if your field names or object structure are correct.

Comment: @JordanRieger "The datatable rows contain 3 columns: id, heading and value."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to put an array of anonymous objects directly into a `JArray`.  This will not work.  Instead, put your row data into `JObjects` and add those to the `JArray`.  You can do that by changing this line:

```
select new { id = row["id"], value = row["reportTitle"] }
```

to this:

```
select new JObject(
           new JProperty("id", row["id"]), 
           new JProperty("value", row["reportTitle"])
       )
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x5KqXy

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you.  It was the one last piece that I needed.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.